# PlSQL showing compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

PL/SQL is showing compilation error. Function is working correctly and successfully compiled, but if running pl/sql query then showing compilation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(
   num  IN  NUMBER,
   num2 IN  NUMBER,
   ans  OUT NUMBER 
) RETURN number IS 
BEGIN 
  ans := num + num2;
  RETURN ans;
END;

CREATE table add1(val1  number(2),val2  number(1),ans  number(3));

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;

DECLARE 
  a1  add1.val1%TYPE;
  b1  add1.val2%TYPE;
  sum add1.ans%TYPE;
BEGIN
  WHILE a1!=-99
  LOOP
    a1 := &a1;
    b1 := &b1;
    sum := f(a1, b1, sum);
    INSERT INTO add1 VALUES(a1, b1, c1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: i have replaced c1 in insert query with sum but still compilation error,,,

Comment: `PL/SQL is showing compilation error`. Where is the error(code, message)? There, in fact, are many errors: 1) you are trying to use `c1` variable, but you haven't declared it; 2) `sum` is a PL/SQL reserved word. So, you either change(recommended) the name of the variable or enclose `sum` in double quotation marks(never do this). Side note: Try not to write functions that return more than one value to the invoker through combination of `return` statement and one or more `out` parameters.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasKrasnov i got your point .now its working,.,, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use IN and OUT in functions. Only in procedures. Correct approach is:

```
   create or replace function f(
       num  number,
       num2 number 
    ) return number is 
    ans number;
    begin 
      ans := num + num2;
      return ans;
    end;
```

UPD: Oh, boy! There are too many errors in your code. Maybe you should describe what you are trying to do with all that stuff.

Comment: `You cannot use IN and OUT in functions` Not true. It's allowable.  The only restriction is, you cannot use that function in SQL, but in PL/SQL, please, go ahead and use it,even though it's a very, very bad practice.

Comment: My bad, didn't know about it. Although I still don't see the reason to use function with OUT parameters instead of procedure with OUT parameters in PL/SQL.